# Dovecot and reconnection to database

Tags: postgresql, dovecot

I've got a setup with Dovecot using a PostgreSQL backend together with vmm. I usually get messages like this into log:

```
dovecot: dict: pgsql(10.0.0.2): Connected to database mail
```

Based on investigation I think it's because Dovecot is losing/closing connection to the PostgreSQL server. Is there any way to tell Dovecot to keep connection alive?

Comment: What about this makes you think that the connections need to stay alive, instead of being cycled occasionally?

Comment: I'm still connected with a bunch of IMAP clients.

Comment: Do you see extra load due to dovecot cycling the connections?

Comment: Well... a little. It's about 100 reconnections per hour roughly. well... I know something I can deal with it, but as it's appearing to increase with numbers of clients ...

Comment: You know what dict is doing in this case, right?

Comment: I assume it's trying to get the path where to put the mail into.